# How is the Dash 8 Q400 so fast?

Tags: efficiency, cruise, dash-8

The Q400 has a cruise speed of 360kts, and on flightradar24 most Q400s that I looked at reached similar speeds during cruise. The ATR 72 has similar specifications yet only flies at 280kts. I'm currently designing a regional turboprop as part of a university assignment and I can't find a drag polar that gives 360kts as anywhere near the optimum speed for L/D ratio, 244kts was the cruise speed for my initial configuration. Is the Q400 likely flying at a much higher, less efficient speed? Why would this be done? Or has better technology allowed it to fly efficiently at this speed?

Edit: According to a pilot on [this](https://community.infiniteflight.com/t/dash-8-cruising-speed/336470) flight sim forum they used to cruise at around 200kts. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4JnuzCLcEo) shows Flybe (budget airliner) cruising at 240kts, FL240. Maybe the flights I've seen on flight radar are operating under different parameters at the moment, with fewer passengers and lower oil prices maybe 360kts is the best speed.

Comment: Are you sure the drag polar is at cruise altitude? 244kts IAS at FL300 may very well be 360kts TAS.

Comment: @EfeBallı It doesn't really change your point, but service ceiling for the Q400 ist FL270. Most cruise below FL250 because they don't have oxygen masks (for passengers).

Comment: @Efe Ballı thought you might be right, 360kts TAS is about 241kts EAS at FL250. I'm fairly sure it's 244TAS though. Here are my optimal climb and cruise TAS https://i.imgur.com/dDP1nmc.png C_do = 0.0273 and C_di = 0.0283. This is a plane designed for a heavier payload than the dash8.

Comment: The designers of Q400 made the plane light enough to be fast. The major weight savings come from main ldg gear, which is so light it collapses approximately on every other landing. Sorry... I'll get  mi coat...

Comment: @Jpe61 hahaha, I'll be sure to include that in my design report.

Comment: Oh dear god don't, you'll fail the course 

Comment: I'm sure I read somewhere that the Q400 cruises at 400kts TAS, it's a major selling point of the Q400 as it cruises _almost_ as fast as a jetliner. I don't have any data as proof, but I don't believe 400 kts is too far off its best range speed.
@Jpe61, not sure about weight but it surely saves a fair bit of drag to retract the LG into the nacelle and eliminate fuselage protrusions for LG housing. 100% agree on LG fragility

Comment: "ATR 72 has similar specifications".  That is not a true statement and negates your entire question. The Q400 is simply a faster aircraft.

Comment: @EfeBallı yes, the Dash 8 series is way more streamlined than the ATRs. I'm pretty these planes were designed with rather different goals in mind, so the speed of Dash 8 is not just about burning more juice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the cruise performance tables for the Q400 at the heaviest and lightest weight (click to view larger):

[image: Q400 Performance Tables]
<sup>Source: from the Dash-8 Q400 performance manual, which came included with a simulator product I purchased. They probably got their data from a QRH (Quick Reference Handbook), which usually includes such tables in the In-Flight Performance section.</sup>

At ISA conditions at FL250, the **long range cruise** is flown between 209 and 188 KIAS (depending on weight) and the **high speed cruise** is flown between 230 and 243 KIAS. The corresponding TAS at FL250 (assuming ISA conditions) are:

- 188 KIAS: 281 KTAS
- 209 KIAS: 312 KTAS
- 230 KIAS: 343 KTAS
- 243 KIAS: 363 KTAS

That last value (for high speed cruise at light weight) seems to agree quite well with the max. cruise speed of 360 KTAS, which one usually find for the Q400. But best range speed at that weight would be around 188 KIAS (281 KTAS), quite a bit slower. At higher weight, the speed differences between best range and high speed cruise are smaller though.

At typical weights the Dash-8 will still be faster than the ATR 72-600. I don't have exact performance tables for that aircraft, but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATR_72#Specifications_(ATR_72-600)) says cruise speed is 280 KTAS. So yes, the Dash-8 is built for higher speed. The biggest difference is the choice of engine: PW150A with **3782 kW** for the Dash, but PW127M with only **1846 kW** for the ATR, more than a **factor two difference**! While this difference probably causes a higher best range speed for the Dash compared to the ATR, in absolute fuel usage the ATR is still more economical.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind sharing where you got these tables?

Comment: @RoryMcDonald I always include a link to the source if it is publicly available. In this case, I couldn't find a public source. I got the tables from the Dash-8 Q400 performance manual, which came included with a simulator product I purchased. They probably got their data from a QRH (Quick Reference Handbook), which usually includes such tables in the In-Flight Performance section. Maybe you can find a QRH on Google somewhere...

Comment: I embedded the source info into the answer, in case a comment clean up ever accidentally sweeps that away.